# push a view from calloutAccessoryControlTapped

Tags: ios, ios7, uiviewcontroller, mapkit

I'm trying to push a view from a callout in my mapView. The following code does not seem to work. Any help is immensely appreciated.

Thank You

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view calloutAccessoryControlTapped:(UIControl *)control
{
   NSLog(@"Tapped Callout");
   srPlayAudio *SrPlayAudio = [[srPlayAudio alloc] initWithNibName:@"nib" bundle:nil];
   SrPlayAudio.fileName = [[view annotation]title];
   [self.navigationController pushViewController:SrPlayAudio animated:YES];
}
```

The console prints Tapped Callout whenever the callout is touched.I don't see any problem with the calloutAccessoryControlTapped method.

Comment: Is your new view really coming from a nib file called "nib"?  Have you looked with the debugger to ensure that `srPlayAudio` isn't nil?  Have you put a breakpoint into the `viewDidLoad` method of `SrPlayAudio` ?

Comment: my navigation controller was nil. I did not notice that. I just solved the issue. As a newbie to the site I can't post the answer now. Will do it once I have the opportunity to do so. Thank you @Paulw11 for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view calloutAccessoryControlTapped:(UIControl *)control
{
  NSLog(@"Tapped Callout");
  srPlayAudio *SrPlayAudio = [[srPlayAudio alloc] init];
  SrPlayAudio.fileName = [[view annotation]title];
  UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:SrPlayAudio];
  navController.navigationBarHidden = NO;
  [self presentViewController:navController animated:YES completion:^{

}];

}
```

Looks like I misunderstood UINavigationController. navigationController was null. The code above works completely fine.